# Facebook Posting on page's wall instead of user's wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using oauth to get offline access token for facebook.

With user (wall) access token, image/text is posted on wall which is right.

But when I use page access token to post some thing on Page than it is not posting on page instead it is posting on user's wall.

Can anyone help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this. It will work. Replace pageID with your own pageID at which u want to post.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variablesForEvent=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
[variablesForEvent setObject:@"my message" forKey:@"message"];
NSString *postToFBEventRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",@"pageID"];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:postToFBEventRequest
                                 parameters:variablesForEvent
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          }];
```